# Parsing (large) JSON with simdjson-go

Tags: json, go

I am planing on using [simdjson](https://github.com/minio/simdjson-go) for parsing very large JSON datasets.

Datasets are divided with newline, so I used [ParseND](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/minio/simdjson-go?tab=doc#ParseND) function for it.

By adapting provided example from the documentation, I was able to get the key and data related to it, however, I am currently lost on how should I access other elements in parsed JSON?

Perhaps if I explain my use case it will be clearer what I seek for - I want to be able to detect a certain string pattern within a JSON key, and if that pattern has a match, I want to access rest of the keys from that JSON line.

```
{"timestamp":"1","name":"xxx1","level":"yyy1","value":"zzz1"}
{"timestamp":"2","name":"xxx2","level":"yyy2","value":"zzz2"}
{"timestamp":"3","name":"xxx3","level":"yyy3","value":"zzz3"}
{"timestamp":"4","name":"xxx4","level":"yyy4","value":"zzz4"}
{"timestamp":"5","name":"xxx5","level":"yyy5","value":"zzz5"}
```

So if I am using:

```
e := obj.FindKey("name", &elem)
if e != nil && elem.Type == simdjson.TypeString {
    v, _ := elem.Iter.StringBytes()
    fmt.Println(string(v))
}
```

to access key "name" and check its pattern, how can I access other keys in that same row? Is this the good approach to begin with?

Additionally, JSON I would like to load is few hundred GB large. How should that be approached? Can *simdjson* handle that out of the box? For smaller JSONs I was using *ioutil.ReadFile()* approach, but I am not certain if that will work on larger datasets.

Thanks in advance for any insihgt!

Comment: If you have detailed questions about some not very common third party library you should ask the authors of that library.

Comment: Well, I hate to answer questions to myself, but the solution is to reuse the *obj* for getting other keys, and using *ParseNDStream*. I will post whole solution once I make detailed tests!

Comment: @bbanelli I also have the same use case, could you please post the solution?